# Documentum: I have to make attribute A of a document, only if attribute B gets one particular value

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, documentum, documentum6.5

Documentum: I have to make attribute A of a document, only if attribute B gets one particular value (if attribB="bang" then "make attribA reuired/NOT_NULL").

a) How can I do this with Oracle triggers (PL/SQL)?
b) How can I do this with Java?
c) or maybe even JS client-side validation? (IMHO, last, emergency case)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via java script validation. In java script you can check if attribute Ba has a value 'BANG' then only proced otherwise pop-up alart message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Krishnendu Dey! I tried out this approach already. The problem is that I haven't found ID, to use getElementById

Comment: In jsp you can add the Id and use it in JavaScript in document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not precise, based on what you did ask you have these options:

- BOF (Business object framework), i.e. TBO logic (Type Based Object) - write your custom Java code for various object events - doSave for example
- depending on client you are using (WDK application, xCP 2.x based on extJS) you can use client validation - use this as last option

P.S. And btw, although it is possible, don't mess with the DB under Documentum for these kind of things.